# Problems with Tensorboard on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm running code from https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials/blob/master/tensorflowTUT/tf15_tensorboard/full_code.py on my own computer, which is a sample of how to use Tensorboard, however, I see nothing from the Tensor board from my computer: every tab of the Tensorflow is empty, saying no XX data is found.

I tried the '--inspect option':

> zhao@zhao-ubuntu:~/Desktop/samples$ tensorboard --logdir = 'logs'
>   --inspect
>            ======================================================================
>          Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)  ======================================================================
>
> No event files found within logdir =

and the '--debug' option:

> zhao@zhao-ubuntu:~/Desktop/samples$ tensorboard --logdir = 'logs'
>   --debug  INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is in debug mode. INFO:tensorflow:Starting TensorBoard in directory
>   /home/zhao/Desktop/samples
>
> INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard path_to_run is
>   {'/home/zhao/Desktop/samples/=': None}
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Multiplexer done loading. Load took 0.0 secs
>
> INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is tag: b'22'
>
> Starting TensorBoard b'22' on port 6006 (You can navigate to
>   http://0.0.0.0:6006)

BTW, I'm using python3.5.1 on my ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem: I typed a redundant space to the command line:

```
tensorboard --logdir = 'logs' --inspect
```

which should be:

```
tensorboard --logdir ='logs' --inspect
```

or:

```
tensorboard --logdir 'logs' --inspect
```

where space represents an equal.

I got this answer from:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3209